# Draw bar chart in windows application using c#

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, mschart, bar-chart

I want to draw a bar in `+ve` and `-ve` direction in chart. Like a line at the Middle of the chart and bar are in both the direction.

Please suggest me how I can draw chart in C#.

Comment: See this thread [C#: Paint own Bar Chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248135/c-paint-own-bar-chart)

Comment: i m using mschart. only draw a line in middle of the chart.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383795/y-axis-start-from-10-rather-than-0-in-mschart-using-windows-application

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ZedGraph](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/) . It can do a lot of charting stuff. [Here](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/samples.html) you can find samples, there are some bar samples there. 
I used it, it's realy easy way to create any chart with this library.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383795/y-axis-start-from-10-rather-than-0-in-mschart-using-windows-application