# y axis start from 10 rather than 0 in mschart using windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

HI i want to start bar from 10 rather than 0. is it possible and how?

```
chart1.ChartArea["ChartArea1"].AxisY.IsStartedfromZero=false

chart1.ChartArea["ChartArea1"].AxisY.minimum=10 //but this line replace 0
```

another command to bar start from 10 in ms chart.

Comment: I think you need to use a different `ChartType` something like [Range Bar Chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456745.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are probably using the the wrong `ChartType`, what your code does is shift the baseline from `Zero` and instead start from `10`

I presume what you really want is a Range Bar chart wherein you will have 2 values per bar representing the low and high values which would help in representing the bar midway.

Something like *Product A  low - 10 High 25* now this should show you a bar extending from 10 to 25. In this fashion you can set up for the other points.

**EDIT**
Now its a bit more clear (from the link) for this you will have to use

```
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Crossing = 10;
```

and remove the `AxisY.Minimum` and you should be fine.

Comment: hi i have upload a graph photo http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/MSWinWebChart/thread/52b70d98-2d8a-4eef-a4e1-fd0534b978da

Comment: @user990897 check my edit, i think this should get what you want

Comment: X-axis value is not show below x-axis. it shows at the middle of graph. and i want to show dotted line below the bar. any suggestion.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8395508/x-axis-label-is-not-shown-at-right-place-in-ms-chart-using-windows-application

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [Bar Chart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456715.aspx) Custom Attributes to know about setting the start point of bar in mscharting.

Comment: Well that's a stacked bar chart