# x-axis label is not shown at right place in ms chart using windows application

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, mschart

problem: X-axis label is not show at the right place. i want below the x-axis and a dotted line to touch the x-axis label from every column bar. Please give ur comments.

Comment: Didn't get you ? what do you mean by column bar this is line graph

Comment: yes u r right. it is line graph but i have one line center of y axis. and both the side i have create y-axis column. i have put chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Crossing = 2; so, x-axis value show at the 2 vlaue of y axis like center of the graph. but i want show all x-axis values below chart area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you want the X Axis labels to be placed below the chart area and not dangling in the center whereby you have the crossing set. In that case you can set it via

```
Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IsMarksNextToAxis = false;
```

This should show the labels in the bottom position and not at the crossing.