# Increase bar chart values with button clicks

Tags: c#, winforms, graph, charts

I am trying to create a graph that will show the progress of a workout. Every five button clicks a tick should be added to the graph. This is a example of how it should look.

[image: 1]

For demonstration purposes I am using a button click, In production the clicks will be every twenty revolutions of a wheel.

```
    private int counter = 0;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        counter++;
        // code will go here
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you are looking for the `//code will go here`? ;) Have you managed to built your barchart at all? [Here is a sample in ASP.NET for getting an idea](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8760/Generating-Bar-Chart-in-ASP-NET)

Comment: yes, or any ideas of how it should work, tutorials, etc. Thanks

Comment: No, I am trying to think of what would be best to use. I could use the .net chart or possibly make a custom chart.

Comment: And you may also use `shapes` in a `winform` using `paint` method to [draw the desired shape](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11208/NET-Shape-Control). Another post that could help you on [drawing charts in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248135/c-paint-own-bar-chart). You could go ahead with `MS Charts` but `paint()` seems to much easier.

Comment: The examples you gave are good, but I need help getting the graph to add a tick every five clicks. Thanks

Comment: Why do you have asp.net AND winforms as tags?

Comment: Because it is going in a winforms application.

Comment: @user973671 validating every five tick as 1 can be done within your button click event. e.g. `counter/5 = 1` you may call the paint method to draw a square from earlier position to the new position. Keep track of the positions for next use.

Comment: @user973671 "Because it is going in a winforms application"   OK, I removed the asp.net tag.

Comment: Before worrying about adding a tick mark, you should begin with having a chart at all (be it a custom control or a standard control).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either a `Bitmap Buffer` or a `panel` to draw on. Here is a headstart: **Just a sample**.
[reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fromhwnd.aspx).

This solution is based on `WinForms` & `Panel_Paint()`. **You may try to add vertical Progress Label and Chart's Y Axis value labeling**.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1(){
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private int counter = 0;
        private int px = 10;
        private int py = 180;
        private int total5Clicks = 0;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            counter++;
            label1.Text = "Total Clicks = " + counter.ToString();
            if (Math.Abs(counter % 5) == 0){
                if (Math.Abs(counter / 5) > 0){
                    total5Clicks = total5Clicks + 1;
                    PaintOnChartPanel(total5Clicks);}
             }
         }

      private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e){           
      }

      private void PaintOnChartPanel(int total5Times)
      {            
        //Add a new Panel Paint EventHandler
        panel1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(panel1_Paint);

        using (Graphics g = this.panel1.CreateGraphics())
        {
            Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Green);
            g.FillRectangle(brush, px, py, 20, 20);                           
            Pen pen = new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.White));
            g.DrawRectangle(pen, px, py, 20, 20);                    

            //add each total5Click into chart block
            g.DrawString((total5Times).ToString(), new Font("Arial", 7), 
            new SolidBrush(Color.AntiqueWhite),
            px + 1, py+8, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
            pen.Dispose();}

            if (py > 20){
                py = py - 20;}
            else{
                MessageBox.Show("Reached Top of the Panel");
                if (px < 200){
                    px = px + 20;
                    py = 180;}
                else{
                    MessageBox.Show("Reached Right of the Panel");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output Form:

[image]

Comment: @user973671 Please give this code a go. It adds each square block from `Bottm to Top` as you would do it in a usual Bar Chart :) not Top to Bottom... Happy to explain the code if you have further questions.

Comment: This is perfect, exactly what I needed,I appreciate your help. There were a lot of good answers, but I am marking this one because it was the most complete, Thanks

Comment: @user973671 glad you got it worked :) please provide any further comments to improve the code or if you have more questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine if you have a multiple of five with

```
bool drawTickMark = clicks % 5 == 0;
```

`%` is the modulo operator which returns the remainder of an integer division. E.g. `13 % 5 = 3` and `13 / 5 = 2` because `2 * 5 + 3 = 13`.

`clicks % 5` will be zero for `clicks = 0, 5, 10, 15, ...`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not much of an ASP.NET guy but here's an algorithm you can use to draw the squares

```
        int perColumn = Height / squareSize;
        int totalColumns = (squareCount / perColumn) + 1;

        for (int y = 0; y <= totalColumns - 1; y++)
        {
            int itemCount = squareCount - (y * perColumn);
            if (itemCount > perColumn)
                itemCount = perColumn;

            for (int x = 0; x <= itemCount - 1; x++)
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(RandomBrush, New Rectangle((column * SquareSize) + 3, (i * SquareSize) + 3, SquareSize - 2, SquareSize - 2))
```

[image]

```
public sealed class ClickGraph : Control
{
    private int squareCount = 1;
    public int SquareCount
    {
        get
        {
            return squareCount;
        }
        set
        {
            squareCount = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private int squareSize = 25;
    public int SquareSize
    {
        get
        {
            return squareSize;
        }
        set
        {
            squareSize = value;
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    public ClickGraph()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.Clear(BackColor);

        int perColumn = Height / squareSize;
        int totalColumns = (squareCount / perColumn) + 1;

        for (int y = 0; y <= totalColumns - 1; y++)
        {
            int itemCount = squareCount - (y * perColumn);
            if (itemCount > perColumn)
                itemCount = perColumn;

            for (int x = 0; x <= itemCount - 1; x++)
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(RandomBrush, New Rectangle((column * SquareSize) + 3, (i * SquareSize) + 3, SquareSize - 2, SquareSize - 2))

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: how are you calling OnPaint(); to add new ticks? Thanks

Comment: `Invalidate()` in the property setter.

Comment: Awesome code, but I'm still trying to get this to work, what does the click event look like, Thanks for your help.

Comment: `clickGraph1.SquareCount++; // increments the amount of squares in the graph`

Comment: I added that but the OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) doesn't seem to be firing, Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I don't know if you're missing something. The class I provided works as a custom control in a WinForms application out of the box. You could update your OP with what you currently have.